# REST url design

Tags: rest, get, put

Let's you have an url like this:

`POST /departments`, which creates a new department
and `POST /employees`, which creates a new employ.

Both url returns a location header for the newly created resource, etc.

Assume that an employee can belong to multiple departments.

> How would you structure the corresponding URL and most important would
>   you use POST or PUT to perform this operation? E.g.: to add Bill to
>   the books department, would you use:

`POST /departments/Books/employees/Bill`

Or:

```
PUT /departments/Books
{
  "employee" : "Bill"
}
```

The former looks to me more semantically correct since anyway in the `POST` body i have more data that characterizes this new relationship. Moreover

`GET /employee/Bill` returns a body that is different from the one returned by:
`GET /departments/Books/employees/Bill`

So to me adding the relationship is like creating a new resources. However I do not like the fact that in
`POST /departments/Books/employees/Bill` I'm explicitly naming the new resource in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the name of the employee before hand it seems the easiest way of doing this is to use PUT

```
PUT /departments/books/employees/bill
```

If resource "Bill" is completely new then return a 201. If "Bill" already exists then return 200.

```
GET /departments/books/employees/bill
```

and

```
GET /dapartments/giftcards/employees/bill
```

and

```
GET /employees/bill
```

should return the **same data**. I'm not sure why it wouldn't if "Bill" is the same resource in both cases.

Comment: Makes sense, however I think that the status code for the PUT should be 204 (no content). The serious GETs return different representation because the employee "Bill" has some department-specific fields (they come from the N:N relationship in the db actually).

Comment: Yeah 204 is fine as well. Just not 201 because the resource isn't being created.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter what your URI looks like, REST based systems don't care.

```
GET {someUrlToDept}
=>
200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+xml

<resource>
    <DepartmentName>Books</DepartmentName>
    <links>
        <link rel="http://myapi.com/rels/employees" href="{someUrlToEmployeesForThisDept}"/>
    </links>
<resource>

POST {someUrlToEmployeesForThisDept}
Content-Type : application/hal+xml

<resource>
    <EmployeeName>Bill</EmployeeName>
    <OtherStuff>...</OtherStuff>
</resource>
```

Comment: I think you're confusing REST and HATEAOS

Comment: @ChadGrant  I do get confused about plenty of things, but I'm quite sure this isn't one of them :-)

Comment: Not trying to be snarky, but the question is about restful url's and I don't think "someUrlToDept" is very helpful given the question.

Comment: @ChadGrant There is no such thing as a Restful URL, it is a contradiction.  URLs must be opaque to REST clients.

Comment: Still think you're missing the point of the question. Regardless of our disagreement about restful url's

Answer (score 0):

There is no unique answer to your question. The relationship between A and B when you have a URI containing "A/B" is left to the developer's (AFAIK).

However, I think that URIs should follow the principle of least surprise, and so have a limited number of meanings.

For me, *A/B* can represent only three possible relationships:

1. "B is an instance of concept A";
2. "B is a concept which is **a part of** instance A";
3. "A is a concept, B is a concept, and B is a kind of A".

Your question is about the use of case 2. I prefer that case 2 be used only for the "is a part of" relationship.

If I apply this logic to **answer your question**, does an employee is *a part of* a particular department?

Certainly not, because you wrote that an employee can work for multiple departments. The relationship between "employee" and "department" is a "works for" relationship, it's an association and not a composition. For this reason, I would not advocate for the use of:

```
/departments/Books/employees/Bill
```

I think an explicit link inside the :

```
/departments/Books
```

ressource, pointing to the:

```
/employees/Bill
```

ressource could be clearer and less prone to misinterpretations on the long term.